# Measure execution time of api calls

Tags: android, kotlin

In my company's android application written in Kotlin, I have 2 Api calls and I want to measure their execution time.

Code looks like this:

```
fun initialization() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val configurationRefresh = async { configurationRepository.refresh() }
        val categoryRefresh = async { categoryRepository.refresh() }

        try {
            configurationRefresh.await()
            categoryRefresh.await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            status.postValue(Status.ShowMaintenance)
        } finally {
              DO SOME IRELEVANT CODE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to measure execution time of configurationRepository.refresh() and categoryRepository.refresh() API calls.
What is the best approach to execute this operation? Thanks

Comment: Look up "kotlin benchmark library" and you'll find some solutions.

Comment: I’m aware of that function. It’s not for benchmarking.  I think you need to do more research on benchmarking on the JVM. It is not nearly so simple to get useful results. Using that function doesn’t take into account JVM warmup, just-in-time compiler behavior, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help people so I will write. I found out that for me the easiest solution is using measureTimeMillis() function in kotlin. It goes like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val time = measureTimeMillis {
            categoryRepository.refresh()   //Api call
        }
        Log.println(Log.VERBOSE, "Api time testing", "$time")
    }
```

The written time in Log is the execution time of the API call.